# Android fragment backstack animation fail after orientation change

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments, android-orientation, fragment-backstack

I have an activity which hosts two fragments with only one shown at a time. Effectively the user, through different environmental conditions, should be able to toggle between the two at any given time.

There is a `LoginFragment` which is the first thing the user sees on login, and a `LockoutFragment` which may replace the `LoginFragment` after a user logs in and we see their account is locked (naturally).

That is the typical case, but there is a case in which `LockoutFragment` is presented first, if say, the user is using the app and their account is locked for some reason, and we re-open the host activity (`LoginActivity`), showing the `LockoutFragment`, but giving them a button to "Return to login", which toggles appearance of the `LoginFragment` (also naturally).

Thus, my goal is to allow a user to toggle between the two fragments, whichever is displayed first. My host activity uses the following functions to achieve this effect:

```
private void showLockoutFragment() {
    if (mLockoutFragment == null) {
        mLockoutFragment = new LockoutFragment();
    }

    transitionToFragment(FRAGMENT_LOCKOUT, mLockoutFragment);
}

private void showLoginFragment() {
    if (mLoginFragment == null) {
        mLoginFragment = new LoginFragment();
    }

    transitionToFragment(FRAGMENT_LOGIN, mLoginFragment);
}

private void transitionToFragment(String transactionTag, Fragment fragment) {
    if (!getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(transactionTag, 0)) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.setCustomAnimations(
                R.animator.fade_in, R.animator.fade_out,
                R.animator.fade_in, R.animator.fade_out);
        ft.addToBackStack(transactionTag);
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, transactionTag);
        ft.commit();
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // non configuration change launch
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            // decide which fragment to show
            boolean shouldLockout = extras.getBoolean(EXTRA_SHOULD_LOCKOUT);
            if (shouldLockout) {
                showLockoutFragment();
            } else {
                showLoginFragment();
            }
        } else {
            showLoginFragment();
        }
    } else {
        // retrieve any pre-existing fragments
        mLoginFragment = (LoginFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_LOGIN);
        mLockoutFragment = (LockoutFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_LOCKOUT);
    }
}
```

These functions work together like a charm, with one exception: when, after initial launch of the app, a user

1. attempts log in,
2. is taken to the lockout fragment,
3. **reorients the device**, and
4. navigates back to the login fragment,

the login fragment is now **present but invisible** - as if the `popEnter` animation was never played. I know it is present because I can still interact with it.

It is also worth noting the following:

- I have `setRetainInstance(true)` on **both** fragments
- This *only* occurs when a user reorients the device from the lockout fragment
- I have tried this on both a simulator and device running Lollipop with same results

Is it possible that the back stack is being corrupted after reorientation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it turns out the issue actually lies in my use of `setRetainInstance`. According to the docs for that method:

> Control whether a fragment instance is retained across Activity re-creation (such as from a configuration change). This can **only be used with fragments not in the back stack**. [emphasis mine]

While this appears rather cryptic to me, it seems that using `setRetainInstance(true)` on a fragment that is on the back stack could simply have unintended consequences. In my case, the fragment seemed to be retained, but its `popEnter` animation was never being called (post-rotation). Again, weird, but I guess just avoid that combination.